# How does Rounding in Python work?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, precision, floating-accuracy

I am a bit confused about how rounding in Python works.
Could someone please explain why Python behaves like this?

Example:

```
>>> round(0.05,1) # this makes sense
0.1
>>> round(0.15,1) # this doesn't make sense! Why is the result not 0.2?
0.1
```

And same for:

```
>>> round(0.25,1) # this makes sense
0.3
>>> round(0.35,1) # in my opinion, should be 0.4 but evaluates to 0.3
0.3
```

**Edit:** So in general, there is a possibility that Python rounds down instead of rounding up. So am I to understand that the only "abnormal" thing that can happen is that Python rounds down? Or may it also get rounded up "abnormally" due to how it is stored? (I haven't found a case where Python rounded up when I expected it to round down)

Comment: Related: `print '%.20f %.20f %.20f'%(.15, .25, .35)`

Comment: @Rob_phi: Not related: your subscript phi is rendered correctly even in the URL display in my address bar [when I click your username]...HOW?!?

Comment: @gariepy If you copy the URL to a text editor it will show up as `http://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob%E1%B5%A9` - some browsers such as Chrome render the escaped unicode characters in the URL bar.

Comment: @Galax: cool, thanks!

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? Note that the halfway case behaviour is different (for actual, honest-to-god halfway cases). For example, in Python 2, `round(1.25, 1)` will give `1.3`, while in Python 3 it gives `1.2`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is actually by design. From Pythons' [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

> The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. **This is not a bug**: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float.

Comment: Yep, in particular "0.15" is internally represented as `0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375`, and "0.35" is `0.34999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375`. Both of which reasonably round down.

Comment: So in general, there is a possibility that it gets rounded down instead of rounded up. So the only "abnormal" thing that can happen is that it gets rounded down? Or may it also get rounded up "abnormally" due to how it is stored? (I haven't found a case where it gets rounded up when I expect it to get rounded down.)

Answer (score 8):

It sounds to me like you need the `decimal` module:

```
from decimal import *
x = Decimal('0.15')
print x.quantize(Decimal('0.1'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Output:

```
0.2
```

Comment: @JonasKaufmann: If you need exact decimal representations, which it sounds like you do, this is the right answer.  Also, this is why Cobol was invented.  And. Still. In. Use. :(

Answer (score 4):

As an example, here is a case where you get rounding up:

```
>>> round(0.0499999999999999999,1)
0.1
```

In this case, 17 "9"s are the minimum number to cause this behavior.  This is because the internal representation of `0.0499999999999999999` is 
`0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125`.