# In Python, how can I get a whole number without decimals from math.sqrt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import math

a = math.sqrt(25)

print(a)
```

My output is 5.0, how can I get a 5 (whole number) instead?

Comment: Rounding (Ex: 5.9 becomes 6) or truncating (ex: 5.9 becomes 5) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Rounding in Python work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620633/how-does-rounding-in-python-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a reduced manner, you can use a 1 line if operator to assign an integer value to the result of `sqrt` if both integer and decimal values are the same:

```
import math

a = math.sqrt(25)
a = int(a) if int(a)==a else a

print(a)
```

Comment: This might not work reliably because of the imprecision of floating point.  Instead of `==` I'd use `math.isclose()`.

Comment: @MarkRansom. No, you definitely want to use `==` here. `sqrt(25)` will give you an exact integer, but `sqrt(25.0000000000001)` will not. You don't want to confuse the two.

Comment: @MadPhysicist is that true for every perfect square? It might work for the specific example of 25 but I know enough about floating point that I wouldn't trust it for all cases.

Comment: @MarkRansom. Yes, barring numbers that are greater than ~2^106. A square root necessarily uses half the bits that the original number did. I can see not wanting to trust anything >2^53, but I've experimented on Intel CPython a bit, and the basics seem to hold, as the definition requires.

Comment: That being said, `isclose` is guaranteed to give you the wrong answer. You want stricter checking here, not looser, regardless of how you achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check and explicitly convert to integer:

```
if x == (y := int(x)):
    x = y
```

Or, without the assignment operator:

```
if x == int(x):
    x = int(x)
```

As of python 3.8, you can use [`math.isqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt):

```
math.isqrt(25)
```

Keep in mind that this will always return an integer, even if the input is not a perfect square.

Comment: Upvoted for `iqsrt`, which is the real answer here.

Comment: @Sören It serves a different purpose. Depends on what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little on what exact behavior you want: do you want to just print the number without the decimal, or do you want to round a number to an integer?

For the print statement, Python tries to convert whatever is passed to it to a String in order to print it, and by default it gives floating point numbers decimal places. To stop that, we can use string formatting:

```
print("{:.0f}".format(a))
```

What this is doing is making a string (the double quotes "") that contains a special format marker (the curly braces {}). Inside the format marker is the code for the desired behavior (0 decimal places on a floating point number). Then we call the .format method of the string and pass the value (a) we want to be used inside the special format marker.

This looks somewhat arcane and ugly, but is the safest method to print what you want because it does not change 'a' and is easily customizable to other printing behaviors.

---

For rounding a number and converting it to an int, you can either use int() or round(): both will take in a float and output an integer that will print cleanly (and be an integer for future computation). There is no requirement for the thing being converted to actually be an integer but there is different behavior for the two functions: int returns the value of the first digit of a number, while round returns the rounded value (IE round(1.9) -> 2, int(1.9) -> 1, etc).